# Erase groups based on a condition with dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data.frame that looks like this

```
data=data.frame(group=c("A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C"), 
                time= c(rep(1,3),rep(2,3), rep(3,3)), 
                value=c(0,1,1,0.1,10,20,10,20,30))

  group time value
1     A    1   0.0
2     B    1   1.0
3     C    1   1.0
4     A    2   0.1
5     B    2  10.0
6     C    2  20.0
7     A    3  10.0
8     B    3  20.0
9     C    3  30.0
```

I would like to find an elegant way to erase a group when its values are smaller < 0.2 in two different time points. Those points do not have to be consecutive.
In this case, I would like to filter out group A because its value at time point 1 and time point 2 is smaller than < 0.2.

```
  group time value
1    B    1   1.0
2    C    1   1.0
3    B    2  10.0
4    C    2  20.0
5    B    3  20.0
6    C    3  30.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this solution you check that no group has more than 1 observation with values under 0.2 as you requested.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
 group_by(group) %>%
 filter(sum(value < 0.2) < 2) %>% 
 ungroup()

#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   group  time value
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 B         1     1
#> 2 C         1     1
#> 3 B         2    10
#> 4 C         2    20
#> 5 B         3    20
#> 6 C         3    30
```

---

But if you are really a fan of base R:

```
data[ave(data$value<0.2, data$group, FUN = function(x) sum(x)<2), ]

#>   group time value
#> 2     B    1     1
#> 3     C    1     1
#> 5     B    2    10
#> 6     C    2    20
#> 8     B    3    20
#> 9     C    3    30
```

Comment: Second base R alternative: `subset(data, ave(value<0.2, group, FUN = function(x) sum(x)<2))`

Comment: `subset(data, ave(value<0.2, group, FUN = sum) < 2)`

Comment: Thank you @Edo and sindri for your time. I highly appreciate

Answer (score 0):

Try this `dplyr` approach:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
data <- data %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(Flag=any(value<0.2)) %>%
  filter(Flag==F) %>% select(-Flag)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   group [2]
  group  time value
  <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
1 B         1     1
2 C         1     1
3 B         2    10
4 C         2    20
5 B         3    20
6 C         3    30
```

Comment: Hello Duck. Thank you for the neat reply as always. I wanted to ask how to do I make sure that I keep the groups where the values are at least two times less than 0.2.  I understand that with this code, I purge all groups where value is at least once less than 0.2. Please forgive my ignorance in advance.

Comment: @LDT It is always a pleasure helping other. You can create an additional var like `Flag2=ifelse(value<=2*0.2,1,NA)` then inspect that values as you want!